# Smooth fadeout/transition between 2 textures in XNA WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I have 2 textures 800x480 (foreground/backgound) which are .png files in XNA Windows Phone 7 application.
I want to fadeout/transision foreground to reveal background. I have huge problem with performance. My idea is only to maipulate `Alpha` channel in one `Texture2D` so i created such a code:

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

private Texture2D _background, _foreground;
private BlendState _blendState;
private uint[] _pixelsForeground;
private uint[] _pixelsBackground;

public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);

    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.Portrait;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 840;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 480;
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

    _background = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"background");
    _foreground = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"foreground");

    _pixelsForeground = new uint[_foreground.Width * _foreground.Height];
    _pixelsBackground = new uint[_foreground.Width * _foreground.Height];

    _background.GetData(_pixelsBackground);
    _foreground.GetData(_pixelsForeground);

    _blendState = new BlendState
    {
        AlphaBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add,
        ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add,
        AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha,
        ColorSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha,
        AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha,
        ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha
    };
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    this.GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;

    for (int x = 0; x < _foreground.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < _foreground.Height; y++)
        {
            uint pixelCanvas = _pixelsForeground[y * _foreground.Width + x];
            uint newPixelCanvas = pixelCanvas - 0x05000000;
            _pixelsForeground[y*_foreground.Width + x] = newPixelCanvas;
            _pixelsForeground[y * _foreground.Width + x] = (newPixelCanvas & 0xFF000000) > (pixelCanvas & 0xFF000000)
                                                                                ? pixelCanvas & 0x00FFFFFF
                                                                                : newPixelCanvas;
        }
    }

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, _foreground.Width, _foreground.Height);
    _foreground.SetData<uint>(0, rect, _pixelsForeground, 0, _foreground.Height * _foreground.Width);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, _blendState);
    spriteBatch.Draw(_foreground, Vector2.One, null, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(_background, Vector2.One, null, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Problem is that it generates poor performance because of:

```
_foreground.SetData<uint>(...)
```

What technique I can use to manage this better?
I'd rather need that manipulation of Alpha channel for other purposes.
Keep in mind that foreground pixels can have different alpha channel already on start something like transparent spots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely the wrong way to approach this. What you want to do is pass a `Color` to the sprite batch's [Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433986.aspx) method that has the appropriate alpha channel.

```
int alpha = 150;
spriteBatch.Draw(tex, pos, new Color(255,255,255,alpha));
```

That way, the GPU handles the alpha blending on your behalf, and your performance issues dissapear :-)

Comment: The problem is that in fact my alpha on foreground have already transparent pixels which are defined by alpha changed so i can't use your solution because then i will change them all.

Comment: Give it a try, I'm pretty sure passing in an alpha value on the color will not override the texture's alpha channel, but will be additive (depending on blend state settings)

Comment: +1 This should definitely work in XNA. You may have to play a bit with the spriteBatch.Begin(...) parameters, but it should work.